# How to Add a Random Custom Gravatar in the WordPress Comments?

Tags: functions, customization, comments, gravatar

I have a client that has 5 different gravatar images, and would like them to be randomly used as the thumbnail for people's comments that have no Gravatar. I know how to change the Gravatar to a custom one, but not display one of the five in the set randomly each time. I know it can be done, because Automattic does it, but I don't now where I could get a look at that code.

Does someone smarter than I know how this may be done?

```
//* Create a custom Gravatar
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'sp_custom_gravatar' );
function sp_custom_gravatar ($avatar) {
    $custom_avatar = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/gravatar.png';
    $avatar[$custom_avatar] = "Custom Gravatar";
    return $avatar;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to do that by code, but it looks like this plugin does exactly that: [Random Avatar Users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/random-avatars-of-user/screenshots/)

Comment: I'm going to have a look at his code and see how he's doing it. I'm sure it would be easy to fork in some manner. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Maybe it helps to get some more answers/response when you follow up this advice: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Nope. That helped none.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the Codex about "Using Gravatars".](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars) There you´ll find a part about "Checking for the Existence of a Gravatar" which works like this:

> The trick to do this is to specify "404" as the default. In this case, the gravatar service will return a 404 error if no gravatar exists, instead of returning some default image. A real image will get a 200 code. It is best to check for 200, as some other errors might be returned as well, for other cases.

There is also a code snippet you can use for that check.

Then build something like this for your default avatars in `single.php/comments.php` or whatever you are using:

```
$default_avatars = array(
                      'yoururl.com/whatever/static/ava1.jpg',
                      'yoururl.com/whatever/static/ava2.jpg',
                      'yoururl.com/whatever/static/ava3.jpg',
                      'yoururl.com/whatever/static/ava4.jpg',
                      'yoururl.com/whatever/static/ava5.jpg'
                   );
$my_default_avatar_now = array_rand($default_avatars);

echo '<img src="'.$my_default_avatar_now.'" class="avatar" />';
```

`array_rand()` seems to not have the best randomness from what you read in the comments on php.net but maybe it´s working fine for you.

This code is untested, so it´s more an explanation of the way you could go then a ready-to-use solution.